# Ionic 2 - Is possible to use camera through mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2, camera

I develop a web application using ionic 2 but cordova camera not working on mobile browser

I need solution for this issue that allows me to capture photo ?

I found this solution but its not as I want

```
<input type="file" ..>
```

I want to open camera when click on button

I saw Instagram website www.instagram.com that allows user to capture photo through browser but I couldn't find solution related to this topic

Comment: Go to that site and view the source.  If that can do it then you already have the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with `<input type="file" ..>` inside an ionic button, and a special css added to the file input which makes it invisible:

```
<button ion-button default icon-left round>
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="picChange($event)" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
<ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
Select picture
</button>
```

and the css file:

```
.file-input {
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
      }
```

You will have a reference to the file in your .ts like this:

```
picChange(event: any) {
        let file = event.srcElement.files[0];
        //you can do anything with this file
    }
```

If you see the result in a mobile browser, it will ask you whether to take a photo with your camera, or use photo library, or browse for a file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the [Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/) for the camera?

Comment: Its work in case I generate APK app .. web browser not work as normal.. may be this plugin doesn't support browser

Comment: Cordova plugins are not supported on browser.